# How to transform with Guava, a List<String> and List<Integer> in another List<Person>?

Tags: java, guava

I've got two lists:

```
List<String> names;
List<Integer> ages;
```

So, I would like to transform these lists in unique List of Person, Person class is like this:

```
public class Person {

 private String name;
 private Integer age;

}
```

How I do it using Guava or another way?

Comment: Describe how you would do it without guava. How does your logic work?

Comment: Does both lists have the same size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the **zip** function which is the territory of functional languages. There is no such function in the Guava library, but you can find it in [Functional Java](http://functionaljava.org/).

Related questions:

[Is there an accepted Java equivalent to Python's zip()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118932/is-there-an-accepted-java-equivalent-to-pythons-zip)

[Google Guava "zip" two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19040802/google-guava-zip-two-lists)